# Colorbox problem link iframe popup jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup, colorbox

I'm using **colorbox** and **jquery** to populate a calendar dynamically.

From the calendar I open a colorbox popup to book a day, and then I update with jquery the parent page containing the calendar by closing the popup.

So far so good, but unfortunately the new content added with the append method of jquery itself contains a link to open a new colorbox popup, and when I click on it the link no longer opens in the popup but in a new page.

I've searched already, finding very old posts suggesting using the live () method, but I honestly don't know how to apply this to my page.

I leave you just 2 lines of example code, if you can help me with some additional code because I can't integrate the information found on the internet in my script:

**function inside the parent page (es. page.php)**:

```
<script>
function add_day(day,content){
if($('#people_day_'+day)){
$('#people_day_'+day).append(content);
}}
</script>
```

**html example div with link inside the parent page (es. page.php)**:

```
<div>
<div id="people_day_2020-10-10"></div>
</div>
```

**script inside the popup page (es. poup.php)**:

```
<script>
parent.add_day('2020-10-10','<a href="page.php?xxx=..." class="iframe">');
parent.$.colorbox.close();
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `live()` is no longer supported by jquery! Use `on()`.

Comment: I use on() in the popup page or in the parent? Do you have an example for this case? Thanks

Comment: in the code you showed you don't use `on()` anywhere. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: hello, sorry but this was the question, because I didn't understand how to use the .on functionality in my context.
with what event do I trigger it if it must be managed dynamically by php only if the operation is successful on the server side? it is not an onclick so to speak.
also, where should I put .on? on the home page or in the popup? the function I call is on the home page.

Comment: ok, i found the solution that's right for me, i reinitialize colorbox after the ajax call, creating a unique function to call every time, like this:

function initialiseColorbox() {
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
}